# viewWillAppear vs Viewdidload ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

When code with iOS navigation application, I have facing with trouble this:

where can I put the method "initdata" for UITableView? in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad?

please help me out.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by init data.

Answer (score 14):

You can put initData as per your requirement of the app,

if your table needs to load data every time with new Data then it should be under

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //initData
}
```

Otherwise, if the table needs to be reload by a single Data which doesn't vary or there is not any editing operation performed on Data , you should use

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   //initData
}
```

Comment: if I put the code in both place. It will runs that code 2 times when I push this tableView into a UInavigationcontroller

Comment: You should place it under "viewwillAppear" only, as your Array depending on change value of child View.It will work.

Comment: Never init data in viewWillAppear. Depending on the way you load view controller into the screen (into other VC or throughout segues) it may not be invoked at all.

Comment: This actually made the difference between the two very clear - viewDidLoad is used specifically for static data/instantiation, whereas viewWillAppear is for dynamic data that could always be changing.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to call that in `initWithNibName:bundle:` or `initWithCoder:` method and release the loaded data in `-(void)dealloc`.

Also, you can have that in `viewDidLoad` and release the loaded data in `viewDidUnload`. But it is better to avoid calling that from `viewWillAppear:`

**Edit:**

I hope that array is depending on the selection in the parent view. In that case, write a setter method, which sets the condition and init the data before pushing the view controller.

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller and depend on that, load the data.
[detailViewController initData:(id)[_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

Comment: in my case, I have a  NSArray need prepare for uitableview. and value of this array depending on change value of child View.