# Loading and unloading data in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I need to load some data in my `UIViewController` to show a `UIPickerView` widget in an iPhone modal view.

I did some research and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8802447/929484) in SO. I proceeded to implement my data reading code in `initWithNibName:bundle:` and data unloading in `dealloc`. However, Instruments kept telling me there was a memory leak when repeatedly showing the modal view, and during debugging I noticed `initWithNibName:bundle:` was called each time the view was shown, but dealloc was never called under normal execution (although it's triggered by a low-memory condition as per Apple's [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) document, and the same applies to `viewDidUnload`).

I ended up loading data in the `viewDidLoad:` method and I released it in `viewDidDisappear:`, the widget shows the data and there are no leaks. However, I'd like to know if there are any good practices in regards to this, because on one comment in Apple's documentation mentions this:

> You should not use this method (i.e. viewDidUnload) to release user data or any other information that cannot be easily recreated.

I assumed the right way was load data in viewDidLoad and releasing all references to it in viewDidUnload, but in practice the latter method is not called unless a low-memory condition arises, and consequently each time the view is displayed, the data is loaded again and the reference to the old data is lost, causing the memory leak.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something bad is happening if `viewDidLoad` is getting called every time your view is shown. `viewDidAppear` should get called, but `viewDidLoad` should only be called the first time the view is needed and if the view is needed and `viewDidUnload` got called.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same when I saw `initWithNibName:bundle:` was being called every time the view was shown, but I'm using a simple UIViewController, and I don't think implementing the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocols would alter the normal behavior. My project's base SDK is **Latest iOS (iOS  5.0)**.

Comment: Well, presuming you're creating a fresh view controller for every modal presentation, yes, you'll get a `loadView` for every one of those. If you cover and then uncover that view, you should not get a `loadView`. On the other hand, you should get a `deallo`c every time you dimiss the modal. If you don't, it would mean you have one or more stray `retain`s on it.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I create a fresh view controller for every modal presentation. The `dealloc` however, is not being called when I dismiss the modal view. I'll check the retains again. Thanks!

Comment: I just checked the way I was creating my modal view and I was over-retaining it, so when I was dismissing it (`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`), it was not being deallocated. I checked the template provided by Xcode and updated my code accordingly and this solved the problem. I think I manually retained the modal view because I was getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS error`. After removing the extra `retain` I found the problem was in the `dealloc` method in another of my controllers. Thanks @smparkes!